# Restarting the command prompt in windows

Tags: windows

just like in windows command prompt we can give commands to restart/log off/shutdown windows...I would like to know what is the command to restart the command prompt itself.
(Possible use case: after making a change in the System Variable i have to restart the command prompt to see those changes take effect)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think is not possible. Just close and open again.

Comment: @Sergi I assume he is talking about doing it within a script, rather than interactively.

Comment: Well, you *could* call `cmd`, but it will spawn a whole new command prompt inside of yours :D (of course, you could ten `exit` the inner command prompt after testing what you want to test).

Comment: @Luaan This doesn't actually work - it will use the environment variables from the parent (i.e. the old variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I thought running `start cmd.exe` would launch a new command prompt with the new environment variable set. However, testing confirms this doesn't work - it respects the environment variables

```
REM This won't work.
SETX ABC 123
START cmd.exe 
EXIT
```

Running `ECHO %ABC%` will not echo 123 in the new window.

However, "runas" can be used to do this:

```
REM This will work.
SETX ABC 123
RUNAS /noprofile /savecred /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% cmd.exe
EXIT
```

Running `ECHO %ABC%` in the new window will now echo 123.

Comment: ok...so START cmd.exe on the command prompt will start a new command prompt window...but i just wanted to know weather i can restart the current command prompt window through some command.

Comment: Firstly, you need to use "runas", not "start" - please re-read my answer :) Secondly, you cannot **restart** a command prompt. You have to spawn a new command window, then close the original window - I've added the "EXIT" command to the end of my script.

Comment: I was referring to the command given in the wont work section...but since it looks like there is no way to just get the command prompt restarted...its better to start a new one(using RUNAS as you mentioned) and exit the current one.